# facebook integration is not working when the mobile have already facebook application and shows the error like "invalid hash key" android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-facebook

In my application i want to integrate the facebook. I wrote all the code for this.But whenever i click the facebook login button it showing one popup like "Invalid key hash and the key hash XXX does not match with any stored key hash"
If my mobile not having facebook application, then it is working. If my mobile  is having facebook app the facebook integration is not possible to me.

for hash key: (oncreate)

```
 try {
            Log.v("TAG_PACKNAME",""+"UUUU");
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "Your package name",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.v("TAG_PACKNAME",""+ Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));  // not printing

            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

i got hash key and release key too. i added both developement key and release key in facebook console. But whenever i click the facebook login button it pop ups like "invalid hash key. the hash key not matched with already stored hashkey"
 please any one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

When you are redirected to Facebook app and when it shows invalid keyhash, The keyhash XXXX doesnot match with any stored keyhashes. Copy the keyHash XXXX add = to that and paste XXXX= in the Key hashes section in Facebook [image]

Comment: the hash key what i gave in facebook console and what it is showing  (in error) are same, but dont know y it is showing

Comment: adding it in the debug key hash and release key has might be causing the error. Place it in the place as shown in the image and try. It might help you

Comment: before this  page we have one page ...like  add the pckage name, class name (which contain fb) after that we have two columns like one for developement key and another for release key na,,, (got it) whatever we give in release hash key that is updated into keyhashes(in your screen)

Comment: add in that place the key which you got in your facebook app key hash error screen

Comment: it means, both the dev and release key need to give in keyhashes(ur screen). ?

Comment: ,if i add two hash keys in key hashes (in ur screen) that is updated in release key (before page) automatically. i tried already. not working

Comment: did you add the key hash which was being shown in the "Key hash doesn't match with any of the stored key hashes" ??

Answer (score 0):

You need generate your release keyhash with this:

Mac/osx:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Windows:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

And your debug key like this:

On OS X, run:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

On Windows, run:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
base64
```

Comment: i got hash keys programatically

Comment: You need get your hash keys from console since a few months the results are differents